# map a new attribute to an observable array using ko mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I am trying to figure out how to add an additional attribute to an observable array using the ko mapping plugin.  so for example if I have data like this

```
var items = [{
  foo1: 'bar1',
  foo2: 'bar2',
  foo3: 'bar3'
}, {
  foo1: 'bar4',
  foo2: 'bar5',
  foo3: 'bar6'
}];
```

and my I can bind to my knockout observable like this

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.items = ko.observableArray('');
}


var vm = new viewModel();


(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
  ko.mapping.fromJS(items, {}, vm.items); // map the data to the
})(jQuery);
```

but what if in the items array I would like each item to have an additional attribute.  such as  editMode: false.  what do I have to do to the mapping to make that happen.  I believe it has something to do with the create callback but I can't quite figure it out.

here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/5/. I can't quite figure out how to use the create function on the mapping to add the additional attribute of editMode with a value of false to each item in the array of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better solution.

You could call the mapping pluging this way:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(items, mapping,vm.items);
```

`mapping` is an object with a `create` function:

```
  var mapping = {
    create: function(options) {
      return new dummyModel(options.data);
    }
  }
```

And `dummyModel` is a temporary object than holds the new properties you want to add, and the ones that come from the plugin:

```
  var dummyModel = function(data) {
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

      // New Properties
            this.editMode = ko.observable(false)
  }
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk5ygtcm/6/) to play with.

Hope this helps.

PD:  Source of info in this link [Pluggin Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)  (*Customizing object construction using “create”*)